# How to import bulk data in documentDB from excel?

Tags: c#, excel, insert, bulkinsert, azure-cosmosdb

I have surfed for a day about how to insert bulk data in documentDB from excel file, but I didn't get any informaion.

I can able to read data from excel file and insert one by one in documentDB

```
Service service = new Service();
    foreach(data in exceldata) //exceldata contains set of rows
    {
    var student = new Student();
    student.id= "";
    student.name = data.name;
    student.age = data.age;
    student.class = data.class;
    student.id = service.savetoDocumentDB(collectionLink,student); //collectionlink is a string stored in web.config
    students.add(student);
    }

Class Service
{
 public async Task<string> AddDocument(string collectionLink, Student data)
        {
            this.DeserializePayload(data);
            var result = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, data);
            return result.Resource.Id;
        }
}
```

Can I insert all records at one instance?

Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update (4/8/15):** DocumentDB just released a data import tool, which supports JSON files, MongoDB, SQL Server, and CSV files. You can find it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436

**Original Answer:**

DocumentDB doesn't support bulk importing from excel files just yet... However, you can leverage DocumentDB's store procedures to make bulk import a bit more friendly!

Check out [Ryan's sample from MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af/sourcecode):

```
/** 
* This script called as stored procedure to import lots of documents in one batch. 
* The script sets response body to the number of docs imported and is called multiple times  
* by the client until total number of docs desired by the client is imported. 
* @param  {Object[]} docs - Array of documents to import. 
*/ 
function bulkImport(docs) { 
    var collection = getContext().getCollection(); 
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink(); 

    // The count of imported docs, also used as current doc index. 
    var count = 0; 

    // Validate input. 
    if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null."); 

    var docsLength = docs.length; 
    if (docsLength == 0) { 
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(0); 
    } 

    // Call the CRUD API to create a document. 
    tryCreate(docs[count], callback); 

    // Note that there are 2 exit conditions: 
    // 1) The createDocument request was not accepted.  
    //    In this case the callback will not be called, we just call setBody and we are done. 
    // 2) The callback was called docs.length times. 
    //    In this case all documents were created and we don't need to call tryCreate anymore. Just call setBody and we are done. 
    function tryCreate(doc, callback) { 
        var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, callback); 

        // If the request was accepted, callback will be called. 
        // Otherwise report current count back to the client,  
        // which will call the script again with remaining set of docs. 
        // This condition will happen when this stored procedure has been running too long 
        // and is about to get cancelled by the server. This will allow the calling client 
        // to resume this batch from the point we got to before isAccepted was set to false 
        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
    } 

    // This is called when collection.createDocument is done and the document has been persisted. 
    function callback(err, doc, options) { 
        if (err) throw err; 

        // One more document has been inserted, increment the count. 
        count++; 

        if (count >= docsLength) { 
            // If we have created all documents, we are done. Just set the response. 
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count); 
        } else { 
            // Create next document. 
            tryCreate(docs[count], callback); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can find reference documentation regarding DocumentDB database-side programming (stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs) here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/

Comment: Link above is broken. Should be: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af