# Best way to store XLSX files in CosmosDB and be able to send the result back in chunks?

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, xlsx

I am looking to store Excel spreadsheets in xlsx format in a CosmosDB database. These sheets could be thousands of rows long so I want to write an api (probably in Node.js) that can get these sheets in smaller pages of data (let's say 50 rows for example).

What would be the best way to store these and how would I get the results out as partial sheets?

Comment: Please take a look at the following Stack Overflow post related to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318716/how-to-import-bulk-data-in-documentdb-from-excel

Comment: Why do you want to store spreadsheets in Cosmos DB?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score -1):

> What would be the best way to store these and how would I get the
>   results out as partial sheets?

You could use [Cosmos DB Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#CSV) to import your data into cosmos db. Excel file is not supported by the tool so you could save your file as csv file which is supported.

If you want to import data in page,you need to use continuation token. Please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#example-bulk-importing-data-into-a-database-program) and my previous case: [How do I get a continuation token for a bulk INSERT on Azure Cosmos DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653343/how-do-i-get-a-continuation-token-for-a-bulk-insert-on-azure-cosmos-db/48658211#48658211).